# Laravel ACL: Policy Class not being read

Tags: acl, laravel-5.1, policy

So in `AuthServiceProvider` I am doing following:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate as GateContract;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;


class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        \App\Post::class => PostPolicy::class
    ];

    /**
     * Register any application authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate  $gate
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(GateContract $gate)
    {
        parent::registerPolicies($gate);

    }
```

**PostPolicy**

```
namespace App\Policies;

use App\Post;
use App\User;

class PostPolicy
{
    /**
     * Create a new policy instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }
    public function view(User $user)
    {
        dd('he was here');//This line NEVER gets executed.
        return $user->type === 'user';
    }
}
```

Comment: Your PostPolicy has name of BriefPolicy? Is that correct?

Comment: Samething is happening to me! I cannot figure out why my policy methods are not getting executed. Did you ever figure out why this was happening?

Comment: @enriqg9 Nope. I discarded the idea of using Policies.

Comment: @Volatil3 In the end I ended up having a typo on the before method and now everything works as expected. Thank you for your response though.

Comment: @enriqg9 would like to know what mistake I was doing or what you did?

Comment: @Volatil3 I believe that you need to pass a second argument to your view method, the first argument is always the auth user, and you would pass your second argument in the controller like `$this->authorize('view', $model);` and then on your view method, for example, `view(User $user, $model)` and then just make the necessary comparisson. But I think that since you are not passing the second argument, Laravel cannot resolve which policy it should use as it is related to the model.